# How did the priests deal with excess blood during the Temple dedication?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, korban, melachim-kings-book-of, blood

What did the priests do with all the excess blood when Solomon dedicated the Temple? They sacrificed 22,000 head of cattle and 120,000 sheep and goats. That would be about 360,000 (US) gallons or 1.36 million liters. There would seem to have to be special provisions to deal with all the blood.

Comment: That's about half of an Olympic size swimming pool.

Comment: @DoubleAA - And who said miracles didn't happen in the Bet Hamikdash? ;-) Too bad Pirkei Avot didn't mention this one. I guess they only had room for 10.

Comment: This wouldn't have been a one time problem - the best estimates suggest that at Passover each year, roughly 250,000 lambs were slaughtered.

Answer (score 8):

The extra blood after each sacrifice was poured at the base of the altar (if it was considered Shirayim, leftover) or the Amah - a channel which led out of the courtyard (if the blood's status is dichuy, invalid to be poured on the base). This is from the Talmud, Zevachim [34b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=29&daf=34b&format=pdf).

The leftover blood which was poured out flowed to Nachal Kidron, and was redeemed by farmers to fertilize their fields:  (from the Talmud, tractate Pesachim [22a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=22&format=pdf))

(Information taken from http://www.webshas.org/zevach/chatas/dam.htm and http://dafyomi.co.il/zevachim/points/zv-ps-034.htm )

Comment: Cool site! http://www.webshas.org